# Size of the sample

Tags: sample-size

What will be the size of sample as compared to population size that we considered it as large sample/ small sample?

Sometimes I see that if n=24 it considered as large sample and sometimes even for size n=60 is considered as small sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to LBogaardt's answer, it's also dependant on the statistical test you're using and the effect size of what you're studying. In genomics we're often looking for small effects across 9 million genetic variants, so we need a huge number of people in our studies. But if you're testing for whether ice cream is colder than coffee and running a t test or mann-whitney test of temperatures, then you're probably fine with 5 of each.

One approach to determining whether your sample size is sufficient is to run a power calculation. This, given an estimated effect size and desired alpha level, will tell you the chance of you detecting a significant effect.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this does not depend on the size of the population but on the size of the *noise* or *error* in the outcome variable. So it depends on *what* you want to measure, what you want to *use* that measure for and what level of error you are *willing to accept*.

Let's say you are in a casino and there's a new game called *Red/Blue*. All you need to do is place money on either *Red* or *Blue* and if your colour wins, it doubles your money.

The probability of either *Red* or *Blue* is not necessarily *50/50* in this game. In fact, you hypothesise that *Red* comes up way more often, so it might be better to place your bet on *Red*. You decide to first observe other people playing, before you start yourself. How many games will you observe, before you dare to play yourself?

Your goal, in this case, is to gain money, so to maximise the expected gains. This relates to what you want to *use* statistics for.

Imagine a situation where *Red* comes up around 90% of the time versus a situation were *Red* comes up about 55% of the time. How will this affect the number of observations you need before you feel confident to start placing bets? This relates to the *noise* in the outcome variable.

Now imagine how things change when you are a risk-seeking person versus a very careful person. This relates to the *alpha level* and the amount of error you are willing to accept.

Comment: It's common to give comments when downvoting. Also, this answer is pretty damn good, if I say so myself. Why any downvotes at all?